# Using Jackson annotations to serialise objects to XML

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm using Spring and Jackson to serialise objects before returning them as XML as part of an API. The Jackson documentation outlines that the root element name returned should match that of the object's class name.

I have the following model. I've explicitly set the root element to equal 'product'.

```
package example.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

In my controller, I'm returning a response containing the list of products retrieved.

```
package example.controllers;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Product>> getProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.productRepository.findById(id));
    }
}
```

When I hit the endpoint, `/api/products/1` I get:

```
<Optional>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Example</name>
    <createdAt>2019-12-18T12:44:12.536+0000</createdAt>
    <updatedAt>2019-12-18T12:44:12.536+0000</updatedAt>
</Optional>
```

Although, I'm expecting:

```
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Example</name>
    <createdAt>2019-12-18T12:44:12.536+0000</createdAt>
    <updatedAt>2019-12-18T12:44:12.536+0000</updatedAt>
</product>
```

How can I use Jackson/`jackson-dataformat-xml` to achieve this as it looks like my annotations have no effect?

Answer (score 1):

Change the endpoint to return a `Product` instead of `Optional`.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
public ResponseEntity<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.productRepository.findById(id).get());
}
```

Note: `Optional.get()` is used here for simplicity. The case of having no `Product` should be properly handled with `Optional` methods like `isPresent()` or `orElse()`.

Comment: This seems correct, just be aware that `Optional` means exactly what it says. It's optional. You need to check if it's present with `Optional.isPresent()`. Depending on your design, you'd likely return a 404 if `isPresent` returns false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In this scenario that works fine... But if I was returning `List<Product>` for example, it falters returning `<List><item>...</item></List>`.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider: thx, updated the answer.
@spudmonkee: in this case, the list needs to be wrapped in an object `Products` and the endpoint would return a single `Products` object.